# Settings wont launch Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME

Tags: gnome, settings, appmenu

I have ubuntu Gnome installed on my laptop, and the settings application wont launch. It makes the animation and briefly shows at the top taskbar, but then goes away. I installed vanilla ubuntu then installed gnome desktop, so when I log into the default ubuntu desktop with unity, it works fine. Tweak tool also works fine as well.

Typing unity-control-center in terminal spits out this command below, and brings up settings but the only setting there is language.

```
ethan@ethan-macbook-ubuntu:~$ unity-control-center
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnm-gtk.so.0: invalid ELF header
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-   1/panels/libnetwork.so
```

Anyone know whats wrong here? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that there is something wrong with the ELF, that is to say the header of the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnm-gtk.so.0 binary file you have installed one possible reason for this could be that the file is corrupt. Since this file is installed by the libnm-gtk0 package you could try the following command to reinstall it in case it is corrupted.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnm-gtk0
```

The other likely candidate for this error would be if you have somehow installed amd64 packages on a 32 bit (i386) version of ubuntu since the 32 bit kernel will not recognise the ELF64 (64 bit binary) as being a valid ELF header which would produce this error also perhaps if the above doesn't fix the problem you should add the output of the following command to your question:

```
uname -a
```

That will print out some information about your kernel and platform that could help diagnose the issue further.